# Instantiating a worker role from a worker role

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role(WR-1) to put messages in Azure Queue. WR-1 is scheduled using Quartz.NET.
I have another worker role(WR-2) that processes the messages on Azure Queue.
I would like to trigger the WR-2 from WR-1 once the queuing activity is finished.
I couldn't find any material on how to instantiate a worker role from another worker role.
Is it possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

If your worker roles are different applications, you could make use of `Service Management API` to create a new deployment for WR-2 from WR-1. What you would do is put the package and configuration files of WR-2 in blob storage and when WR-1 has done putting all the messages in the queue, you create a new deployment of WR-2. To create a deployment programmatically using Service Management API, please see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460813.aspx. However you would need to ensure that once WR-2 has done all the data, it is destroyed by WR-1 so that you don't keep on incurring charges.

Other possibility is to run your worker role instances to run in `Master/Slave` configuration. Let's say there are 2 instances of your worker role running. One of the instance would be a `Master` instance which will put the data in the queue and once data is put in the queue, it will write a message in some other queue signalling `Slave` that it is done writing the data. `Slaves` will constantly poll this other queue and once they find that `Master` has finished putting the data, they can start fetching the data from the queue containing actual data and process them. To decide which instance will be `Master` and which ones will be `Slave` you could make use of `Lease Blob` functionality. The instance which is able to acquire lease on the blob will be the `Master` while other instances be `Slave`.

Comment: After looking at both the options, it looks like first option is cost effective in terms of azure pricing model. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would like to understand reason behind the condition you mentioned "If your worker roles are different applications", how is it different if they are from same application.

Comment: Regarding your 1st comment, 1st option is cheaper if you create and destroy your WR-2 properly. If you leave WR-2 running, then you would be incurring unnecessary charges. About 2nd comment - By different applications, I mean your worker roles (WR-1 and WR-2) in two different solutions and not in one.

Comment: seeing the cost that we are able to reduce using this deploy and destroy strategy of WR-2 as and when required. Is there any strategy that we can use in reducing the cost of WR-1 too as an alternative to Quartz.NET approach? I believe using Quartz.NET is going to make WR-1 run forever.

Comment: Like you're creating an instance of WR-2 from WR-1, you could do the same for WR-1 as well by creating an instance of WR-1 from a service running outside of Windows Azure. It's the same Service Management API. However I would not recommend it as it creates an external dependency. If costing is the concern, you could host WR-1 in an Extra Small instance which would cost one instance about $15.00 / month ($0.02 * 750 hrs).